# Bottom and Right Behavior on jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following jQuery code for a sample program I was working on

```
    $('#left').click(function(){
        $('.box').animate({
            left: "-=40px",
        }, function(){/* End of Animation*/});  
    });

    $('#right').click(function(){
        $('.box').animate({
            right: "-=40px",
        }, function(){ /* End of Animation*/}); 
    });

    $('#up').click(function(){
        $('.box').animate({
            top: "-=40px",
        }, function(){/* End of Animation*/});  
    });

    $('#down').click(function(){
        $('.box').animate({
            bottom: "-=40px",
        }, function(){ /* End of Animation*/}); 
    });
```

Here is the HTML for it

```
    <div class="box">a box</div>

    <div id="navArrows">
        <button id="left" class="navigationArrow">&larr;</button>
        <button id="up" class="navigationArrow">&uarr;</button>
        <button id="right" class="navigationArrow">&rarr;</button>
        <button id="down" class="navigationArrow">&darr;</button>
    </div>
```

And the CSS

```
#navArrows {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    background: #333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.navigationArrow {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background: white;
    color: #222;
}

#up {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
}

#left, #right {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
}

#right {
    right: 20px;
    left: inherit;
}

#down {
    bottom: 20px;
    top: inherit;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
}

.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #a7f;
    color: white;
    border: solid 4px #a1f;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    opacity: 0.5;        
    position: relative;            
}
```

Now what this supposedly needs to do is move the `div.box` based on the button that is ticked. To make it semantic I used the corresponding positions for each of the button tick. But somehow. I'm having a hard time understanding the code.

The code works however, whenever I use the following: 

For Right and Left Buttons
`{left: "-=40px"} and {left: "+=40px"} or {right: "-=40px"} and {right: "+=40px"}`

For Up and Down Buttons
`{top: "-=40px"} and {top: "+=40px"} or {bottom: "-=40px"} and {bottom: "+=40px"}`

Any insight upon this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Quoting from W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#relative-positioning)**

> If neither 'left' nor 'right' is 'auto', the position is over-constrained, and one of them has to be ignored.
>
> - If the 'direction' property of the containing block is **'ltr'**, the value of **'left' wins** and 'right' becomes -'left'.
> - If 'direction' of the containing block is **'rtl'**, **'right' wins** and 'left' is ignored.

---

This is because the **browsers work on `ltr`** direction as default and `right` property is ignored.

Consider these steps :

1. You click on -> Right arrow, the `div` changes as follows :

   ```
   <div class="box" style="right: -40px;">a box</div>
   ```
2. Then you click on <- Left arrow, the `div` changes as follows :

   ```
   <div class="box" style="right: -40px; left: 0px;">a box</div>
   ```

   *Notice - `left:..` is added after `right:..` property.
3. Now you click on -> Right arrow again,

   ```
   <div class="box" style="right: -80px; left: 0px;">a box</div>
   ```

   *The `right:..` is reduced by `-40`, but the `left` is still `0` which is applied.

In the above case the `right property is ignored - **[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oL24k2Lt/11/)**.

---

Now, if you override the `ltr` by,

```
body  {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

the `left` property is ignored.
**[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oL24k2Lt/12/)**